# How to give same permissions to FTP user & Home user?

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

`OS: Ubuntu 16.04.6`

I have created one FTP server using `vsftpd`. I initially followed instructions from the following link.

[How To Set Up vsftpd for a User's Directory on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04)

But above tutorial as well as most other resources teach about making a server for a directory under home. But I wanted to make it for two of my external drives; `/media/Drive-1` & `/media/Drive-2`

I did so by using,

```
sudo mount --bind /media/Drive-1/ /home/home_user/ftp_user
```

Now the problem is,

- Whenever I make a directory, copy a file etc. using (say) `gftp`, my `home_user` can't change/delete it.
- Similarly, if I make a directory or file using `home_user`, the `ftp_user` cannot change/delete it.

Now some directories are owned by 'home_user' and some are 'ftp_user'. Is there a way to grant all the directories same access, so anything I create/send through `gftp` or `ssh` or manually as the home user is accessible by both `home_user` and `ftp_user`.?

PS: Drives are EXT4 file-system.

Comment: Important info we need: are those drives are NTFS formatted?

Comment: @Rinzwind I updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now some directories are owned by 'home_user' and some are 'ftp_user'. Is there a way to grant all the directories same access, so anything I create/send through gftp or ssh or manually as the home user is accessible by both home_user and ftp_user.?

Yes. There are 3 sets of permissions:

- user
- group
- others

Each with 3 options: read and/or write and/or execute. When users 'home_user' and 'ftp_user' are in the same group they can do the same actions on files as if they would own them.

Easiest (and more secure then the other way around) is to add your 'home_user' to the group 'ftp_user' is set. That would be (change the 2 between {} to what it is for you):

```
usermod -a -G {group_ftp_user} {home_user}
```

If ssh and ftp use different users and groups you could also create a new group 1st

```
sudo groupadd {new_group}
```

and then add all 3 to that new group with the 1st command.

Also see

```
local_umask=
```

in

```
/etc/vsftpd.conf
```

You need to set that to 007 (it will now be set to 700).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added my `ftp_user` into my `home_user group`. I added a directory and a file using `gftp`. The output of `ls -l` is; `drwx------ 2 ftp_user ftp_user 4096 Jul 17 13:10 tempp`. I guess `ftp_user` has a group of its own. What should be done in this case.

Comment: Like I said in the answer: add "home-user" to group "ftp_user". "ftp_user into my home_user group" No. I said add "home_user" to frp group. Please keep security in mind. You do not want an ftp user to be able to alter files the user of the system owns.

Comment: Yeah you are right, I did the reverse. Now I added 'home_user' into group of 'ftp_user' which has the same name, i.e. 'ftp_user'. But even after doing this, when I added a folder using `gftp` i get this; `drwx------   2 ftp_user ftp_user 4096 Jul 17 14:46 new_directory`. Shouldn't I be getting, `drwxrwxrwx   2 ftp_user ftp_user 4096 Jul 17 14:46 new_directory`

Comment: no you need drwxrwx--- (or 770 for directories) and drw-rw---- (for files; executable bit should be a manual action) But that should be an option in the ftp software you use. It is probably set to 700.

Comment: ah see "local_umask" in "/etc/vsftpd.conf".

Comment: That solved the problem. I set it to 770 though! Thanks!!